# How do I find this element in Selenium (button on page to press)?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to press the "grid" class button that is on a web page but I am having trouble. Here is the HTML:

```
<li id="prodlist" class="prodtab">
    <span> Products</span>
        <div class="grid" onclick="goToView('productGrid');"></div>
        <div class="list" onclick="goToView('productList')"></div>
</li>
```

Here is what I tried but it gives **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[contains(@class, 'grid')]")).click();
```

Comment: Any reason you have to use xpath? Why not a css selector like `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#prodlist .grid"));`

Comment: I don't have to use path. I tried your code but I get the same error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#prodlist .grid"}

Comment: Do you have javascript on that page that creates that element dynamically? Or is that static html?

Comment: Yes it is in a frame. I am having trouble switching to the frame because of the space in the frame name. Here is the html: <iframe style="visibility: visible;" class="framePage ajaxStoreNumberAppendSrc" src="http://local.flyerservices.com/sob/fln/?cc=ncs&amp;storeNumber=6425"></iframe>   and this is what I tried:  driver.switchTo().frame("framePage.ajaxStoreNumberAppendSrc");   but it throws a NoSuchFrameException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this kind of problems is usually either *switch to an iframe*, if the element is inside it:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("iframe.ajaxStoreNumberAppendSrc"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame); 

// then, search for element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'grid')]")).click();
```

Or, make an *explicit wait* to wait for element to become present:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'grid')]")));
```

Comment: I just looked on the page he was trying to access and in this case, he was trying to access it in the iframe. He'll want `driver.switchTo().frame("flyerFrame");`

Comment: Yes it is in a frame. I am having trouble switching to the frame because of the space in the frame name. Here is the html: <iframe style="visibility: visible;" class="framePage ajaxStoreNumberAppendSrc" src="http://local.flyerservices.com/sob/fln/?cc=ncs&amp;storeNumber=6425"></iframe>   and this is what I tried:  driver.switchTo().frame("framePage.ajaxStoreNumberAppendSrc");   but it throws a NoSuchFrameException

Comment: Parker i'm not really sure where you are seeing that the frame is called flyerFrame :S

Comment: @ClaudeBastien My mistake, I was getting that from your last question's website which incidentally has the same product list/grid layout.